# Will updating Wordpress affect the wp-includes folder?

Tags: php, wordpress, updates, overwrite

I'm customizing a Wordpress site, and want to alter a file in the wp-includes folder, specifically the media.php file. If I change that file and Wordpress has an update, will it overwrite what I have done?

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it probably will. Depending on what you want to do you should try if you can solve your problem with the [plugin api](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

Comment: Okay thanks. I figured as much, I just wanted to change a few lines, but it's probably better that I use a plugin anyway.

Comment: Yes it probably is. You will save yourself a lot of headache when it comes to debugging, too because you can just disable the plugins.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule you shouldn't edit anything out of the wp-content folder.  It may or may not be bad to change something in wp-includes, but best not to risk it.

You can either write a plug-in that does what you need, or, if the change is too minor to be worth a whole plug-in, you might be able to edit some of the theme files with the extra code (though then your changes are tied into the theme, which may not be so horrible if they are display related).